# Why we defined `def hello() = "world"`, but we can invoke it as "hello"?

Tags: scala

If we have a method:

```
def hello() = "world"
```

I'm told that we can call it as:

```
hello()
```

also

```
hello
```

They both work and will output `world`, but why?

---

PS:

I see some words in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340289/342235:

> No, actually, they are not. Even though they both call a method without parameters, one is a "method with zero parameter lists" while the other is a "method with one empty parameter list"

But I still not understand why `hello` would work

Answer (score 3):

Scala allows the omission of parentheses on methods of arity-0 (no arguments):

You should only omit the parenthesis when there are no side effects to the invokation though

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Comment: Could you tell me more about the underlying? Why they say "No, actually, they are not (the same)."?

Comment: Well interestingly (for me) var and def definitions live in the same namespace (according to the Odersky book). So there are some mechanisms I don't fully understand to resolve what you mean when you write `hello`. It could be you're looking for the `var`, the method with no params or the method with empty params.

Comment: @Freewind: The "not the same" comment is about method definitions, not calls.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in **Oliver Shaw's** answer, Scala lets you leave out the parenthesis in functions with 0 arguments. As for *why*, it's likely to facilitate easy refactoring.

If you have a function that takes no arguments, **and produces no side-effects**, it's equivalent to an immutable value. If you always call such functions without parentheses, then you're free to change the underlying definition of the function to a value without having to refactor it everywhere it's referenced.

It's worth noting that `val` definitions are actually modeled as 0-arity methods in scala (unless specified with a `private final` beforehand).

Scala does something similar with its treatment of arity-1 functions defined on classes. You are allowed to omit the dot and the parenthesis. For example:

```
case class Foo(value: String) {
  def prepend(value2: String) = Foo(value2 + value)
}

Foo("one").prepend("two")
// is the same as...
Foo("one") prepend "two"
```

This is because Scala models all operators as arity-1 functions. You can rewrite `1 + 2` as `1.+(2)` and have it mean the same thing. Representing operators as fully-fledged functions has some nice qualities. You can expect to pass an operator anywhere that you could pass a function, and the definition of the operator is actually defined for class instances (as opposed to a language like C#, where the infix operators are actually static methods that use special syntactic sugar to let them be represented as infix).