# What is the purpose of double method brackets in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a code

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = print {CL().f()()()}
}

case class CL() {
  def f()()() = 1
}
```

You can see there a method call `f()()()`. But if I execute `f()` it returns the same result.

So what is the difference betweenn `f()()()` and `f()` in Scala?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Scala, methods can have multiple parameter lists:

```
def f(x: Int)(y: Int, z: String)(w: Boolean) = "foo"
f(1)(2, "bar")(true) //returns "foo"
```

Multiple parameter lists are useful for several reasons.  You can read more about them on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684185/why-does-scala-provide-both-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters-pe) question.

Also in Scala, an empty argument list can be optionally omitted:

```
def f() = "foo"
f //returns "foo"
```

The choice of using an empty parameter list is generally governed by convention, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877953/why-to-use-empty-parentheses-in-scala-if-we-can-just-use-no-parentheses-to-defin) question.

So, if you have multiple empty argument lists, you can omit any of them:

```
def f()()() = "foo"
f()()() //returns "foo"
f()() //returns "foo"
f() //returns "foo"
f //returns "foo"
```

Comment: Yes, multiple parameter lists is a form of currying.  Read more about currying in Scala: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala