# Issue with companion objects in scala

Tags: scala

The below code compiles fine (it is a simple companion object tutorial)

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Colours { def printColour: Unit }
object Colours {
private class Red extends Colours { override def printColour = { println ("colour is Red")} }
def apply : Colours = new Red
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Colours
defined object Colours
```

when i try

```
val r = Colours
```

it works fine, but when i use

```
r.printColour
```

I get an error

```
<console>:17: error: value printColour is not a member of object Colours
   r.printColour
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `val r = Colours`, its not calling your `apply` on companion object because your apply method does not take params because it does not have `()`.

see example,

```
class MyClass {
  def doSomething : String= "vnjdfkghk"
}

object MyClass {
  def apply: MyClass = new MyClass()
}

MyClass.apply.doSomething shouldBe "vnjdfkghk" //explicit apply call
```

So, you have to call apply on your companion object

```
val r = Colours.apply
```

Or else, you must have parenthesis with `apply` (**empty-paren**), so that you don't need to call `.apply` explicitly.

eg.

```
class MyClass {
  def doSomething : String= "vnjdfkghk"
}

object MyClass {
  def apply(): MyClass = new MyClass()
}

MyClass().doSomething shouldBe "vnjdfkghk"
```

### very useful resources

[Difference between function with parentheses and without [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601150/432903)

[Why does Scala need parameterless in addition to zero-parameter methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337955/432903)

[Why to use empty parentheses in Scala if we can just use no parentheses to define a function which does not need any arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878038/432903)

Comment: I would also add that in the REPL you can see the type of r: Colours.type

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis to your `apply` method definition ...

```
def apply(): ...
```

... and the `Colours` object invocation.

```
val r = Colours()
```

Then it will work as desired.

```
r.printColour  // "colour is Red"
```